# ggplot2 make missing value in geom_tile not blank

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the `geom_tile()` layer in the ggplot2 data visualization package for R, when a cell contains no data it is not drawn. E.g. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html and search for "missing value".

I would like to change this behavior to show the minimum value over all the tiles.  Is this possible and if so how?

Additional context:  when I use

```
stat_density2d(aes(x=x,y=y, fill=..density..), geom="tile", contour=FALSE)
```

I would like the regions with no density to look very similar to the regions with very little density.  As it is now, if say the color spectrum is from blue to red and the background is white, then there when there is no data in a tile it is white and when there is a single data point in a tile is blue.

Adding a pseudo count to the data seems possible, but how do I know in advance how to distribute the pseudo-counts? and in the case when there are faceting?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for (a reproducible example would help a lot), but perhaps you could try `+scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0,...))` and replace `...` with a suitable maximum value?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This issue can also be fixed by an option in scale_fill_continuous

```
scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'salmon')
```

Edit below:

This only fills in the explicitly (i.e. values which are NA) missing values. (It may have worked differently in previous versions of ggplot, I'm too lazy to check)

See the following code for an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
Data <- expand.grid(x = 1:5,y=1:5) %>%
  mutate(Value = rnorm(25))

Data %>%
  filter(y!=3) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=Value))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'salmon')

Data %>%
  mutate(Value=ifelse(1:n() %in% sample(1:n(),22),NA,Value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=Value))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'salmon')
```

An easy fix for this is to use the complete function to make the missing values explicit.

```
Data %>%
  filter(1:n() %in% sample(1:n(),22)) %>%
  complete(x,y) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=Value))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'salmon')
```

In some cases the expand function may be more useful than the complete function.

Comment: Can you post a full example? I can't get this to work (ggplot2 v3.0.0)

Answer (score 29):

If your data is a grid-like data, how about adding another `geom_tile()` for NA by `subset()`?

```
# Generate data
pp <- function (n, r = 4) {
  x    <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len = n)
  df   <- expand.grid(x = x, y = x)
  df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
  df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6)
  df
}
pp20 <- pp(20)[sample(20*20, size = 200),]

df_grid  <- expand.grid(x = unique(pp20$x), y = unique(pp20$x))
df_merge <- merge(pp20, df_grid, by = c("x", "y"), all = TRUE)

# Missing values
ggplot(df_merge, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_tile(data = subset(df_merge, !is.na(z)), aes(fill = z)) +
  geom_tile(data = subset(df_merge,  is.na(z)), aes(colour = NA),
    linetype = 0, fill = "pink", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image: an example]

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach.  Thanks!

Comment: i tried the code but the legend for NA didn't show up.. the author of ggplot2 mentioned this as well in this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/MbYp5K03X3w  so how did you get that NA legend??

Comment: Code gives an error: "Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette." because of "colour = NA".

Answer (score 8):

For posterity, here is the right solution compatible with `ggplot2` version 1.9.3

```
+ theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="blue", colour="blue")
```

- In joran's answer, the `plot.background` is the whole plot including the title and legend etc. The `panel.background` is the area where the data appears.
- In the latest version of ggplot2, `opts` has been replaced with `theme` and `theme_rect` has been replaced with `element_rect`.
- In specifying `element_rect`, `color` is the boundary of the rectangle while `fill` is the interior of the rectangle.

I had originally used,

```
+ geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="blue")
```

but when adding `geom_raster` rather than `geom_tile` over the the background and generate `pdf` output, pdf viewers had a very hard time rendering the plot, using substantially more cpu cycles and memory.

Answer (score 3):

This answer may perhaps be a bit too 'cute', but could one solution be to simply change the background color of your plot to be the minimum color in your scale? For instance:

```
+ opts(plot.background = theme_rect(colour = "blue")
```

If your plot has a more complex structure and this ends up making the background blue in areas where you don't want that to happen, you could plot a `geom_rect` layer first that extends to through the ranges of your data only.