# How can I force ggplot's geom_tile to fill every facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot's geom_tile to do 2-D density plots faceted by a factor. Every facet's scale goes from the minimum of all the data to the maximum of all the data, but the geom_tile in each facet only extends to the range of the data plotted *in that facet*.

Example code that demonstrates the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

data.unlimited <- data.frame(x=rnorm(500), y=rnorm(500))
data.limited <- subset(data.frame(x=rnorm(500), y=rnorm(500)), x<1 & y<1 & x>-1 & y>-1)

mydata <- rbind(data.frame(groupvar="unlimited", data.unlimited),
                data.frame(groupvar="limited", data.limited))

ggplot(mydata) +
  aes(x=x,y=y) +
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ groupvar)
```

[image: facet]

Run the code, and you will see two facets. One facet shows a density plot of an "unlimited" random normal distribution. The second facet shows a random normal truncated to lie within a 2x2 square about the origin. The geom_tile in the "limited" facet will be confined inside this small box instead of filling the facet.

```
last_plot() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-5,5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-5,5))
```

[image: specified limits]

These last three lines plot the same data with specified x and y limits, and we see that neither facet extends the tile sections to the edge in this case.

Is there any way to force the geom_tile in each facet to extend to the full range of the facet?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for a combination of `scales = "free"` and `expand = c(0,0)`:

```
ggplot(mydata) +
  aes(x=x,y=y) +
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ groupvar,scales = "free") + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Given the OP's clarification, here's one option via simply setting the panel background manually:

```
ggplot(mydata) +
  aes(x=x,y=y) +
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ groupvar) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") + 
  opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "blue"),panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor = theme_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: No, I want all the facets to have the same scale. Basically, I just want solid blue outside the 2x2 box in the limited side, to indicate that there is zero density there. In other words, I don't want the scales to shrink to the range of the data, I just want to cover the whole area with geom_tile without changing the scale.

Comment: In that case you're better off just setting the panel background manually. I'll update with an example...

Comment: @Ryan - You can also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906661/ggplot2-make-missing-value-in-geom-tile-not-blank) for another option, although I believe that assumes you have the density values in hand.