# ggplot2: Curly braces on an axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In [answering a recent visualization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13999/visualizing-2-letter-combinations/14028#14028) question I really needed braces to show a span on an axis, and I can't figure out how to do it in ggplot2.  Here's the plot:

[image: example plot]

Instead of a tick mark, I'd really like the y axis label "Second letter of two-letter names" to have a brace extending from 1 to 10 (the vertical span of the red and blue second letters).  But I'm not sure how to make that happen.  The x axis could benefit from similar treatment.

Code is available in the linked CrossValidated question (and unnecessarily complicated for this example, so I won't show it).  Instead, here's a minimal example:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)
y <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)
qplot(x=x,y=y) +
  scale_x_continuous("",breaks=c(.5,2.5),labels=c("Low types","High types") )
```

[image: minimal example]

In this case, a brace from (0,1) for low types and from (2,3) for the high types would be ideal instead of tick marks.

I'd rather not use `geom_rect` because:

- The tick marks will remain
- I'd prefer braces
- It will be inside the plot instead of outside it

How would I accomplish this?  The perfect answer would have:

- A nice, smooth, thin curly brace
- Drawn outside the plotting area
- Specified via a high-level argument (ideally a range-type object passed to the `breaks` option in `scale_x_continuous`)

Comment: Untested, but your question seemed familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178763/how-to-add-braces-to-a-graph/6179288#6179288

Comment: @joran: Hoping for a ggplot2-specific solution though.  I guess since your (very cool) answer is grid-based not lattice-based it should be able to be adopted.  But I still don't know how to turn off the tick marks, plot things outside the plotting area, etc.

Comment: Any solution will almost certainly involve mucking about with grid. That other code wasn't mine (I'm not that good with grid) I just thought it might make for a good starting point for you, or others.

Comment: It's handy, that's for sure.  I guess my concern (in addition to the ones stated previously) is that it's still kludgy.  ggplot2 is so beautiful about specifying data separately from presentation, and then I'd have to go draw almost with a pencil to get things the way I want them using the fancy curves you've provided.  Seems like the right way to do it conceptually speaking would be as to pass a span object as one element of a list you pass to breaks in scale_x_continuous().

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:** Be sure to see [this related Stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35633239/2727349) if you need to save the plot with ggsave() and have the brackets persist in the saved image.

---

The OP requested the bracket be off the plot.  This solution uses `axis.ticks.length` in combination with `axis.ticks = element_blank()` to allow the brace to be outside the plotting area.
This answer builds upon those of @Pankil and @user697473: we will use `pBrackets` R package -- and include pictures!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(pBrackets) 
x <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)
y <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)
the_plot <- qplot(x=x,y=y) +
  scale_x_continuous("",breaks=c(.5,2.5),labels=c("Low types","High types") ) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(.85, "cm"))


#Run grid.locator a few times to get coordinates for the outer
#most points of the bracket, making sure the 
#bottom_y coordinate is just at the bottom of the gray area.
# to exit grid.locator hit esc; after setting coordinates
# in grid.bracket comment out grid.locator() line
the_plot
grid.locator(unit="native") 
bottom_y <- 284
grid.brackets(220, bottom_y,   80, bottom_y, lwd=2, col="red")
grid.brackets(600, bottom_y,  440, bottom_y, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

A quick note on @Pankil's answer:

```
## Bracket coordinates depend on the size of the plot
## for instance,
## Pankil's suggested bracket coordinates do not work
## with the following sizing:
the_plot
grid.brackets(240, 440, 50, 440, lwd=2, col="red")
grid.brackets(570, 440, 381, 440, lwd=2, col="red")
## 440 seems to be off the graph...
```

[image]

And a couple more to showcase functionality of `pBrackets`:

```
#note, if you reverse the x1 and x2, the bracket flips:
the_plot
grid.brackets( 80, bottom_y, 220, bottom_y, lwd=2, col="red")
grid.brackets(440, bottom_y, 600, bottom_y, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

```
## go vertical:
the_plot
grid.brackets(235, 200, 235, 300, lwd=2, col="red")
grid.brackets(445, 125, 445,  25, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes but how can you save this?  ggsave won't add the brackets

Comment: Nice answer. But it would benefit from an explanation on how to export the plot to a PDF. I've managed to save it to PNG via RStudio's Export button, but failed with the usual solutions like ``ggsave(...)``, ``pdf(...)...dev.off()`` Maybe some function from the ``grid`` package is designed for that, like ``gridArrange()``, but I couldn't quickly find a solution.

Comment: Oh wait: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633239/add-curly-braces-to-ggplot2-and-then-use-ggsave

Comment: PatrickT -- I've added the SamanthaDS post that you linked to the answer.  Thank you both.

Comment: `grid.brackets()` do not seem to start and stop where the `x1` `y1` `x2` `y2` parameters tell them to! (they look very good, just can't get them to where they're supposed to be)

Answer (score 20):

Another solution using a function that draws a curly bracket.

Thanks Gur!

```
curly <- function(N = 100, Tilt = 1, Long = 2, scale = 0.1, xcent = 0.5,
                  ycent = 0.5, theta = 0, col = 1, lwd = 1, grid = FALSE){

# N determines how many points in each curve
# Tilt is the ratio between the axis in the ellipse 
#  defining the curliness of each curve
# Long is the length of the straight line in the curly brackets 
#  in units of the projection of the curly brackets in this dimension
# 2*scale is the absolute size of the projection of the curly brackets 
#  in the y dimension (when theta=0)
# xcent is the location center of the x axis of the curly brackets
# ycent is the location center of the y axis of the curly brackets
# theta is the angle (in radians) of the curly brackets orientation
# col and lwd are passed to points/grid.lines

           ymin <- scale / Tilt
           y2 <- ymin * Long
           i <- seq(0, pi/2, length.out = N)

           x <- c(ymin * Tilt * (sin(i)-1),
                  seq(0,0, length.out = 2),
                  ymin * (Tilt * (1 - sin(rev(i)))),
                  ymin * (Tilt * (1 - sin(i))),
                  seq(0,0, length.out = 2),
                  ymin * Tilt * (sin(rev(i)) - 1))

           y <- c(-cos(i) * ymin,
                  c(0,y2),
                  y2 + (cos(rev(i))) * ymin,
                  y2 + (2 - cos(i)) * ymin,
                  c(y2 + 2 * ymin, 2 * y2 + 2 * ymin),
                  2 * y2 + 2 * ymin + cos(rev(i)) * ymin)

           x <- x + xcent
           y <- y + ycent - ymin - y2

           x1 <- cos(theta) * (x - xcent) - sin(theta) * (y - ycent) + xcent
           y1 <- cos(theta) * (y - ycent) + sin(theta) * (x - xcent) + ycent

           ##For grid library:
           if(grid){
              grid.lines(unit(x1,"npc"), unit(y1,"npc"),gp=gpar(col=col,lwd=lwd))
           }

           ##Uncomment for base graphics
           else{
              par(xpd=TRUE)
              points(x1,y1,type='l',col=col,lwd=lwd)
              par(xpd=FALSE)
           }

}


library(ggplot2)
x <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)
y <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)
qplot(x=x,y=y) +
  scale_x_continuous("",breaks=c(.5,2.5),labels=c("Low types","High types") )

curly(N=100,Tilt=0.4,Long=0.3,scale=0.025,xcent=0.2525,
      ycent=par()$usr[3]+0.1,theta=-pi/2,col="red",lwd=2,grid=TRUE)
curly(N=100,Tilt=0.4,Long=0.3,scale=0.025,xcent=0.8,
      ycent=par()$usr[3]+0.1,theta=-pi/2,col="red",lwd=2,grid=TRUE)
```

[image: result plot]

Comment: For the non-mathematics such as myself - If you convert angle to radians internally with `theta <- angle*pi/180`, you can use `angle` as a function argument - I find this easier.

Answer (score 13):

Here is kludgy solution in `ggplot` that constructs a line drawing that vaguely resembles a curly bracket.

Construct a function that takes as input the position and dimensions of a curly bracket.  What this function does is to specify the co-ordinates of an outline drawing of a bracket and uses some math scaling to get it to the size and position desired.  You can use this principle and modify the co-ordinates to give you any desired shape.  In principle you can use the same concept and add curves, ellipses, etc.

```
bracket <- function(x, width, y, height){
  data.frame(
      x=(c(0,1,4,5,6,9,10)/10-0.5)*(width) + x,
      y=c(0,1,1,2,1,1,0)/2*(height) + y
  )
}
```

Pass that to `ggplot` and specifically `geom_line`

```
qplot(x=x,y=y) +
    scale_x_continuous("",breaks=c(.5,2.5), labels=c("Low types","High types")) +
    geom_line(data=bracket(0.5,1,0,-0.2)) +
    geom_line(data=bracket(2.5,2,0,-0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.  You could combine with the answer here to move the braces closer to the axis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001710/how-can-i-force-ggplots-geom-tile-to-fill-every-facet/7001873#7001873

Answer (score 9):

as @user697473 suggested `pBrackets` is the elegant solution.

It works best with the default plotting commands but to make it work with GGplot2 use the `pBracket::grid.brackets`. I'm including the code to make it easy for try it out.

Starting with **your code..**

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)
y <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)
qplot(x=x,y=y) +
  scale_x_continuous("",breaks=c(.5,2.5),labels=c("Low types","High types") ) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

the last line removes the ticks you didn't want.
Now the `pBrackets`

```
library(pBrackets)  # this will also load grid package
grid.locator(unit="native")
```

now using your cursor identify the point on the graph where the brackets start and end. You will get the corresponding coordinates in the 'native' unit. now feed them in the command below

```
grid.brackets(240, 440, 50, 440, lwd=2, col="red")
grid.brackets(570, 440, 381, 440, lwd=2, col="red")
```

You can add the brackets anywhere on the graph or even add text using `grid.text`.

[image]

Hope this helps! Thank you `pBrackets`!

Pankil!

Answer (score 4):

The new `pbrackets` package may help: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pBrackets/index.html.

Comment: Nice! It imports `grid`, so should work with ggplot2.

Comment: A good project, but not super easy to use. See the follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633239/add-curly-braces-to-ggplot2-and-then-use-ggsave

Answer (score 2):

#== EDIT: ggbrace replaced the curlyBraces package

This answer is really late, but for braces inside the plotting area I made a small package [ggbrace](https://github.com/nicolash2/ggbrace) that lets you have curly braces with the coordinates you specify (easy to use):

basically:

```
devtools::install_github("NicolasH2/ggbrace")
library(ggbrace)
library(ggplot2)
```

you can customize x and y coordinates and where the bracket points to. In this specific case:

```r
x <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)
y <- c(runif(10),runif(10)+2)

qplot(x=x,y=y) +
  scale_x_continuous("",breaks=c(.5,2.5),labels=c("Low types","High types") ) + 
  geom_brace(aes(x=c(0,1), y=c(0,-.3)), inherit.data=F, rotate=180) + 
  geom_brace(aes(x=c(2,3), y=c(0,-.3)), inherit.data=F, rotate=180)
```

[image]

EDIT: If you want the braces outside of the plotting area, you can set some ggplot parameters. It is described in a little more detail on the ggbrace github page.

```r
qplot(x=x,y=y) +
  geom_brace(aes(x=c(0,1), y=c(-.4,-.7), label = "Low types"), inherit.data=F, rotate=180, labelsize=5) + 
  geom_brace(aes(x=c(2,3), y=c(-.4,-.7), label = "High types"), inherit.data=F, rotate=180, labelsize=5) +
  coord_cartesian(y=range(y), clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.05), units="npc"))
```

[image]