# Adding underbrace after using coord_flip() on ggplot output

Tags: r, ggplot2, curly-braces, ggpubr

I'm trying to add an underbrace horizontally at the bottom of a ggplot output whose x-y has been flipped (using `coordin_flip()`). I'll using the `mtcars` example data for illustration.

```css
library(ggpubr)

data("mtcars")
dfm <- mtcars
# Convert the cyl variable to a factor
dfm$cyl <- as.factor(dfm$cyl)
# Add the name colums
dfm$name <- rownames(dfm)
# Subset the data
head(dfm[, c("name", "wt", "mpg", "cyl")])

# Sort by group and by ascending order

g <- ggbarplot(dfm, x = "name", y = "mpg",
          fill = "cyl",       # change fill color by cyl
         color = "white", # Set bar border colors to white
          palette = "jco",  # jco journal color palett. 
          sort.val = "asc",  # Sort the value in dscending order 
          sort.by.groups = TRUE, # Sort inside each group
          x.text.angle = 90 # Rotate vertically x axis texts
          ) + labs(title="Brand & MPG", y = " ", x = " Brand") + coord_flip()
```

Then I want to add a horizontal curly bracket at the bottom of the `ggplot` object to have the original plot looks like this.

[image: plot w/ underbrace]

so I referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001799/ggplot2-curly-braces-on-an-axis) and called the `ggbrace` package, modifies the code by adding this following line:

```css
g + geom_brace(aes(x=c(0,-3), y=c(0,35), label = "something"), inherit.data=F, rotate=90, labelsize=5) + coord_cartesian(y=range(dfm$mpg), clip = "off")

# coord_cartesian() is used in order to put the underbrace outside of the plotting area (at the bottom).
```

However, `R` returns an error message:

```css
Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

Any suggestions on how to adjust the arguments inside the `geom_brace()` function to achieve the desired result with minimal modification?

Comment: That is not an error but a warning. I still see the braces being drawn on the plot.

Comment: @RonakShah I think the error lies in the fact that `geom_brace()` was unable to deal with axis whose values is not numeric, hence, it still puts the brace "inside" (instead of "outside") the plotting grid (which also causes the flipped y-axis to shift upward in order to give the brace some space) even after `coord_cartesian()` was called. I am wondering if there's a way to trick ggplot to assume the flipped y-axis as numeric?

Comment: Maybe turning it into factor? `dfm$name <- factor(rownames(dfm))` but that doesn't change anything in the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seem to indicate that you cannot use `coord_flip` and `coord_cartesian` simultaneously, so first, you have to enter all the `coord_cartesian` parameters into `coord_flip`.

Then, as `x` is categorical, some modifications have to be done so `geom_brace` and `coord_flip` understand the inputs in the same way.

Finally, you have to rotate 270 degrees instead of 90.

It would result this:

```r
ggbarplot(dfm, x = "name", y = "mpg",
               fill = "cyl",       # change fill color by cyl
               color = "white", # Set bar border colors to white
               palette = "jco",  # jco journal color palett. 
               sort.val = "asc",  # Sort the value in dscending order 
               sort.by.groups = TRUE, # Sort inside each group
               x.text.angle = 90 # Rotate vertically x axis texts
) + labs(title="Brand & MPG", y = " ", x = " Brand") + 
  geom_brace(aes(x=c(-1,0), y = c(0,35), label = "something"), inherit.data=F, rotate=270, labelsize=5) +
  coord_flip(clip="off", expand = FALSE,x=range(seq_along(dfm$name))) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0., 0., 0.5, 0.), units="lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, many thanks for clarifying this. It really helps.