# How to plot a heat map with irregular data in ordinates in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Suppose I want to plot the following data:

```
# First set of X coordinates
x <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.2)
# Angles from 0 to 90 degrees
angles <- seq(0, 90, length.out = 10)
# Convert to radian
angles <- deg2rad(angles)
# Create an empty data frame
my.df <- data.frame()
# For each angle, populate the data frame
for (theta in angles) {
  y <- sin(x + theta)
  tmp <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, theta = as.factor(theta))
  my.df <- rbind(my.df, tmp)
}

x1 <- seq(0, 12, by = 0.3)
y1 <- sin(x1 - 0.5)
tmp <- data.frame(x = x1, y = y1, theta = as.factor(-0.5))
my.df <- rbind(my.df, tmp)

ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y, color = theta)) + geom_line()
```

That gives me a nice plot:

[image]

Now I want to draw a heat map out of this data set. There are tutorials [here](http://rud.is/b/2016/02/14/making-faceted-heatmaps-with-ggplot2/) and [there](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/) that do it using `geom_tile` to do it.

So, let's try:

```
# Convert the angle values from factors to numerics
my.df$theta <- as.numeric(levels(my.df$theta))[my.df$theta]
ggplot(my.df, aes(theta, x)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = y)) + scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")
```

[image: Too bad]

That does not work, and the reason is that my x coordinates do not have the same step:

`x <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.2)` vs `x1 <- seq(0, 12, by = 0.3)`

But as soon as I use the same step `x1 <- seq(0, 12, by = 0.2)`, it works:

[image: Tada!]

I real life, my data sets are not regularly spaced (these are experimental data), but I still need to display them as a heat map. How can I do?

Comment: Did you take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001710/how-can-i-force-ggplots-geom-tile-to-fill-every-facet ?

Comment: geom_tile() uses the smallest step in the data to determine the size of tiles. The smallest step in your example is so small that the tiles are no longer visible. So you need to create a coarser dataset. E.g. by rounding theta and x. Or interpolate the values of y to a coarse grid.

Comment: @bVa looking at it right now. I tried and and could not make it work

Comment: Something seems strange about your theta axis in the graph provided: why is the range so small when the theta in the data is much larger?

Comment: I converted it in radians

Comment: I see — you should probably add `library(pracma)` (and `library(ggplot2)`) to your MWE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `akima` to interpolate the function into a form suitable for heat map plots.

```
library(akima)
library(ggplot2) 
my.df.interp <- interp(x = my.df$theta, y = my.df$x, z = my.df$y, nx = 30, ny = 30) 
my.df.interp.xyz <- as.data.frame(interp2xyz(my.df.interp))
names(my.df.interp.xyz) <- c("theta", "x", "y")

ggplot(my.df.interp.xyz, aes(x = theta, y = x, fill = y)) + geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")
```

[image]

If you wish to use a different resolution you can change the `nx` and `ny` arguments to `interp`.

Another way to do it with just `ggplot2` is to use `stat_summary_2d`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(my.df, aes(x = theta, y = x, z = y)) + stat_summary_2d(binwidth = 0.3) + 
scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")
```

[image]