# How do I connect between consecutive lines for different data group in R?

Tags: r

[image]

```
  z$Months <- as.factor(z$Months)
  z$Months <- factor(z$Months, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"))

  sp1<-ggplot(z,aes(x=stm1, y=sml1),size=1) + 
    geom_line(aes(color=Months))+
    ggtitle("soil temperature vs soil moisture")+
    labs(x="stm1 (deg C)", y = "sml1 (mm)")+
    scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
                      values=c("#800000","#DC143C","#FFA07A","#FFD700","#BDB76B","#6B8E23","#2E8B57","#008080","#00CED1","#4682B4","#191970","#8A2BE2"))
  sp1
```

I have plotted relationship between two variables sml1 and stm1 based on months, but there are gaps in between different months data. How do I connect the gap between the lines, so that the color of the connecting line is same as that of either of the lines to be connected.

Comment: In my opinion, best practice would be to manipulate the underlying data accordingly

Comment: It is more likely because the ending value of previous month is not equal to the starting values of the current month. A little data manipulation could fix this.

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput(z)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If the missing values are simply NA's, then the following should work.

```
scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'salmon')
```

I recommend checking out this link. 
[ggplot2 make missing value in geom_tile not blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906661/ggplot2-make-missing-value-in-geom-tile-not-blank)