# ggplot2 question - How to plot a heat map with undefined log values

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create a genus level heatmap for microbial community identified in my samples. The abundance ranges from 0 to 1. I would like to log-transform the abundance for better visualizing. However, I concern that the log(0), which indicates the absence of bacteria, will not be able to be visualized. I am trying to color these blanks (undefined log values or Inf values) on my heatmap, but I struggle to figure out how to do it.

My data frame is:

```
Gene    Sample      Abundance      Log10.abundance
A          1          0.0186        -1.7306
B          2            0             -Inf
C          3         7.79E-06       -5.108
D          4          0.0031        -2.5103
E          5            0             -Inf
...       ...         ...              ...
```

My code was:

```
ggplot(data=heatmap, mapping=aes(x= Sample, y= Gene,fill= Log10.abundance)) + 
geom_tile() +
xlab(label = "Sample") + 
scale_fill_distiller(name = "Log10(Abundance)", palette = "RdYlGn")
```

I greatly appreciate if you could have any help to resolve this problem!

Comment: Please add your code and a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/11570343) using `dput()`

Comment: log(0) is -Inf. You could replace -Inf with NA. ggplot will then show this in grey.

Comment: @RichardTelford Thank you very much for your suggestion. However, do you know how to change the grey color as this color was hard to distinguish from dark blue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906661/ggplot2-make-missing-value-in-geom-tile-not-blank